# Circular import issue on multiple python files

Tags: python, init, circular-dependency

I'm currently making an arcade-like system game with python. I separated my project into multiple files. `gtn.py` is responsible for the "Guess the Number" game. `startup.py` was supposedly used for first time startup such as ascii text main menu and game choosing. `main.py` is for connecting in between the files.

Now the system is shortly explained like this. `startup.py` starts, allowing player to choose their game, which only has 1 game atm, `gtn.py`. This was the code for the game choosing

```py
## startup.py

# Startup
class Startup:
    print(tl.logo)
    tl.write("Welcome to the Arcade! Choose the game you want to play!\n")
    tl.delay(2)
    print("[1] Guess the number!")
    tl.delay(1)
    print("[2] Memory cards")

# Startup
class StartUpProcess:
    def ChoosingStartup():
        gamechoose = input("")
        if gamechoose == "1":
            tl.clean()
            game.gtnclass.gtngame()
```

The `startup.py` file imports the `gtn.py` surely, because they need the game from it.
The code above called the `gtngame()` function which is inside the `gtnclass` class, which is inside the `gtn.py` file. Now all the gameprocess works well, until you asked to return to the main menu.

Now the first time I tried importing the `startup.py` and calling the `ChoosingStartup()` function. But you probably guessed it gives circular import problem.

I tried several solutions including creating new function for both startup and game in `__init__.py` file, didn't work either. If you want to see more detailed code, please refer to [this repository](https://github.com/ClamorBits/ClamorArcade/tree/dev) inside the `dev` branch

Comment: Your code snippet has no imports. Please update your question with some sample code which demonstrates circular imports.

Comment: How do you expect us to help with an import error, when you have not shown any of the actual import statements??